# How do you tune a piano?

Tags: piano, tuning

Ok so I am visiting my grandparents and I am going to practice piano at their house for about a month. But, when I started playing it, I noticed that the piano was out of tune buy a full QUARTER tone. So, obviously, I need to tune it. But, because of COVID, no piano tuner is coming over.

**So, I must take matters into my own hands. How do I tune a piano?**

Comment: Is it basically in tune with itself and sounding OK? Or has it gone honkey-tonk?

Comment: ["If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Hey, easier than trying to tunafish

Comment: "So I must take matters into my own hands."  No, no, you definitely must NOT.

Comment: Sometimes tuners leave instruments flat deliberately because it's not clear that the instrument can withstand the increased tension needed to bring it to A=440 Hz.  I would not try raising the pitch of a piano as my first piano tuning project.

Comment: "So, obviously, I need to tune it": From what you've written, this is not at all obvious.

Comment: First rule "do no harm". A piano brought up to pitch may fall out of tune (inconsistently) after a short time (days or less). Strings may break due to the increase in tension - this is less likely if it is done in stages. Is it playable? Safer not to try it.

Comment: Did you ever try this? And if yes, what kind of results did you get?

Comment: @Aaron Nah man, might try it though. That piano I was talking about, is still out of tune lol

Comment: @CarlWitthoft the tunafish has more scales.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is, "you don't". Without proper training, it's very easy to damage the instrument.

With that significant caveat ...

A search for "[how to tune a piano yourself](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20tune%20a%20piano%20yourself)" will turn up a variety of instructional videos. [Here's one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSiRAhtFEsk) that seems especially promising to me.

You'll need the right tools for the job, also. Again, a search for "[tools for piano tuning](https://www.google.com/search?q=tools%20for%20piano%20tuning)" will give you the results you need.

Comment: While there may be "instructional videos,"  there is a huge risk of a random untrained and unskilled person totally borking the piano.   IMNSHO the correct answer is "Don't do it"

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thanks, Carl. I don't know why I didn't edit my post earlier to include your essential cautionary note.

Answer (score 4):

It might be obvious to one who has absolute pitch. But if the whole piano is out by that quarter tone, the majority of people would not notice. Unless they played along to a recording that *was* at concert pitch. It may have been tuned thus on purpose. If it's only certain notes, or one string out or two/three, then it's a different matter. But if it's in tune with itself, let sleeping dogs lie.

You will need certain tools, the hammer being crucial - use the wrong size, and you could end up wrecking the pegs. You won't be able to use a tuner, like you would with a guitar. It's often a few hours for an experienced tuner to pull up a piano, so I believe it's a bad idea for you to attempt this.

If it was my piano, I wouldn't let you near the inside, and would question the mindset of grandparents who are happy for you to experiment on their pride and joy.

Comment: If it's their pride and joy, I assume they'd keep it in tune. Source: Have grandparents with badly-tuned piano that hasn't been used in decades. (Not that I'm disagreeing with anything else in your answer.)